# webscraping with beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the table from a website that contains the Current interests rates. I used python with beautiful soup but I can't locate the html parts. Please send help ! thank you.

I only need to scrape the current interest rates table, not everything else and convert it into csv file. Here is the link to my webiste: https://www.global-rates.com/en/interest-rates/libor/american-dollar/usd-libor-interest-rate-12-months.aspx
here is the picture of the current interests rate table:
[image]

I tried something like this:

```
import bs4 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

URL = 'https://www.global-rates.com/en/interest-rates/libor/american-dollar/usd-libor-interest-rate-12-months.aspx' 

response = requests.get(URL)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.title)
print(soup.title.string)
print(len(response.text))

table = soup.find('table', attrs = {'class':'tableheader'}).tbody
print(table)

columns = ['Current interest rates']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

trs = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n', '') for td in tds]
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index = columns), ignore_index = True)
df.to_csv('libor.csv', index = False)
```

but this gave me attribute errors: "None Type' object has no attribute 'tbody'

oh I also want to make automatically scraping the Mondays' interests rate if that's possible.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt with just pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Get all tables on page
dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.global-rates.com/en/interest-rates/libor/american-dollar/usd-libor-interest-rate-12-months.aspx')

# Find the Current interest rates table
df = [df for df in dfs if df.iloc[0][0] == 'Current interest rates'][0]

# Remove first row that contains column names
df = df.iloc[1:].copy()

# Set column names
df.columns = ['DATE','INTEREST_RATE']

# Convert date from november 02 2020 to 2020-11-02
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

# Remove percentage sign from interest rate
df['INTEREST_RATE'] = df['INTEREST_RATE'].str.replace('%','').str.strip()

# Convert percentage to float type
df['INTEREST_RATE'] = df['INTEREST_RATE'].astype(float)

# Add day of the week column
df['DAY'] = df['DATE'].dt.day_name()

# Output all to CSV
df.to_csv('all_data.csv', index=False)

# Only Mondays
df_monday = df[df['DAY'] == 'Monday']

# Output only Mondays
df_monday.to_csv('monday_data.csv', index=False)

# Add day number of week (Monday = 0)
df['DAY_OF_WEEK_NUMBER'] = df['DATE'].dt.dayofweek

# Add week number of year
df['WEEK_OF_YEAR_NUMBER'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekofyear

# 1. Sort by week of year then day of week
# 2. Group by week of year
# 3. Select first record in group, which will be the earliest day available of that week
df_first_day_of_week = df.sort_values(['WEEK_OF_YEAR_NUMBER','DAY_OF_WEEK_NUMBER']).groupby('WEEK_OF_YEAR_NUMBER').first()

# # Output earliest day of the week data
df_first_day_of_week.to_csv('first_day_of_week.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example to scrape the "Current interest rates":

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.global-rates.com/en/interest-rates/libor/american-dollar/usd-libor-interest-rate-12-months.aspx'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for row in soup.select('table:has(td:contains("Current interest rates"))[style="width:208px;border:1px solid #CCCCCC;"] tr:not(:has([colspan]))'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td')]
    all_data.append(tds)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['Date', 'Rate'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                Date       Rate
0   november 02 2020  0.33238 %
1    october 30 2020  0.33013 %
2    october 29 2020  0.33100 %
3    october 28 2020  0.32763 %
4    october 27 2020  0.33175 %
5    october 26 2020  0.33200 %
6    october 23 2020  0.33663 %
7    october 22 2020  0.33513 %
8    october 21 2020  0.33488 %
9    october 20 2020  0.33713 %
10   october 19 2020  0.33975 %
11   october 16 2020  0.33500 %
```

And saves `data.csv`:

[image]

---

EDIT: To get only mondays, you can do this with the dataframe:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df[df['Date'].dt.weekday==0])
```

Prints:

```
         Date       Rate
0  2020-11-02  0.33238 %
5  2020-10-26  0.33200 %
10 2020-10-19  0.33975 %
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrej ! This looks amazing ! Is it possible to make it grab only Mondays' data ?

Comment: it seems like it still saves as the entire table although I can see it prints out only Mondays. Is there a way to make it save only Mondays as csv file ?

Comment: @Anna You can do `df[df['Date'].dt.weekday==0].to_csv('mondays.csv', index=False)`

Comment: One last quick question, is it possible to do, give me all the mondays, but if monday is a holiday (doesn't exist) give me Tuesday for that week ?

Comment: @Anna I have added the first day of the week smarts to my answer for you. In short, you want to add a week number of the year and the day number of the week then sort by both, group by week number and select the first record. This will give you the earliest available for that week.

Comment: Thank you Adam !